# Format numbers into text

Tags: excel

I have following two numbers in excel:

```
670047
164004100000
```

and want to format as follow:

```
000.000.670.047
164.004.100.000
```

How can I use TEXT function for my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=TEXT(A1,"000\.000\.000\.000")
```

`\` escapes possible decimal separator.